# "was capable of" what?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Cinder felt her finger twitch, the closest thing to a flinch her body
>   was capable of.

[Source](http://www.freevampirenovels.com/0/2993_8.html)

I can't understand this sentence.
I think "be capable of" aways connects with something, but here it doesn't.

Comment: "her body was capable of (doing)". The *doing* part is implied and can be omitted.

Comment: @user3169, She was capble of slightly flinching her body?

Comment: I think "being capable of ( almost ) flinching" ( Look at the phrase "closest thing" )

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of "A being the closest thing to B"?

Comment: Yes. When I first asked the question. I had many confusions: "the closest thing", whether it repersents an object. "flinch", whether its a noun or a verb here, and the "was capable of" ...
Now, I think I understand the sentence with your help. The question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rephrase as

> Cinder felt her finger twitch, *and a "twitch"* was the closest thing to a "flinch" *that* her body was capable of.

A twitch is a small movement (to twitch is a verb with the same meaning). A flinch is a larger movement (often an instinctive motion to avoid something). In the original sentence "twitch" is a verb, but "flinch" is a noun.

So her body was not capable of a flinch  (perhaps she was too weak or tired) but it was capable of a twitch of the finger. The relative clause doesn't need the word "that" when "that" is the object of the clause.

Compare:

> A bicycle is the closest thing to a car (that) I own

Comment: Got it. A gerund can operate an object.

Answer (score 0):

"flinch" here is a verb.

"the closest thing" is the subject.

This sentence means "She barely can flinch her body".